# is it possible to migrate the git LFS file from github to another repo

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am store the source code repo's large font file in Github LFS right now. Because the brandwidth is reach the maxiumn and I could not pull the file from LFS, is it possible to migrate the LFS from Github LFS to another repo(only migrate the large file, the source code still store in github)? I have tried to replace the LFS url to another repo address, but seems did not work. This is how I implement it using this command:

```
git config lfs.url https://codeup.aliyun.com/6d2349c42d48700c27f5f963/cv/cv_render.git/info/lfs
```

Is it possible to make the LFS files store in another location? I have searching, but only found to migrate from normal repo to LFS repo.